# How to give error in a label if value entered in a record already have a value in another field?

Tags: c#, registration

I have three textbox in the web form, which is username, password and IC number that the user have to enter to register. if the IC number the person entered, matches the IC value of any record in the database, it will update the username and password that the person have typed into the username field and password field of that record that have the matching IC. The updating part is fine but What I would want to do is if the record in the database for username and password of the nric entered is filled up, I would like to have a error in a label saying that this NRIC already have a username and password. Help

**Etc, If I entered S9583728F in the NRIC box, and want to register a account, but since in my table S9583728F already have a username and password which is settsser and ddddd, I want it to give me, this NRIC already have a username and password.**

[image]

[image]

Error
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    Guid guid;
                    guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                    string sql = @"UPDATE patient 
                            SET 
                            pUserName = @pUserName,
                            pPassword = @pPassword
                            WHERE pIC = @pIC";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIC", txtIC.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pUsername", txtUsername.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPassword", txtPassword.Value);



                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;

                    con.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT patientID, pUsername, pPassword FROM patient WHERE pIC = @pIC;";

                    int id = (cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null) ? Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) : 0;
                    if (id > 0)
                    {
                        Session.Add("ID", id);
                        Session.Add("Username", txtUsername.Value);
                        Session.Add("Password", txtPassword.Value);
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Value, true);
                        Response.Redirect("registered.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblErrorMessage.Text = "IC does not exist";
                    }
                }


                /*
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    lblErrorMessage.Text = "IC does not exist";
                }
                */

                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply query the database and see if the IC value is already there, before you attempt to insert the new record.

Comment: I added my codes @CM Kanode

Comment: I forgot to add my codes just now , and got a vote down!!. The updating part is fine but What I would want to do is if the record in the database for username and password of the nric entered is filled up, I would like to have a error in a label saying that this NRIC already have a username and password. @CM Kanode

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `UPDATE` Query as below:

```
string sql = @"UPDATE patient 
                        SET 
                        pUserName = @pUserName,
                        pPassword = @pPassword
                        WHERE pIC = @pIC and pUserName='' and pPassword =''";
```

**Solution 2:** write a seperate function and continue with UPDATE if it returns false else display warning message.

```
            boolean IsIDExist()
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();                   
                string sql = @"SELECT count(*) from  patient                           
                        WHERE pIC = @pIC" and pUserName!='' and pPassword !=''";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIC", txtIC.Value);

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                con.Open();

                if(Convert.ToInte32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())>0)
                return true;

                return false;
            }
```

**Complete Code:**

```
            boolean IsIDExist()
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();                   
                string sql = @"SELECT count(*) from  patient                           
                        WHERE pIC = @pIC" and pUserName!='' and pPassword !=''";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIC", txtIC.Value);

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                con.Open();

                if(Convert.ToInte32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())>0)
                return true;

                return false;
            }

   if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                Guid guid;
                guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                string sql = @"UPDATE patient 
                        SET 
                        pUserName = @pUserName,
                        pPassword = @pPassword
                        WHERE pIC = @pIC and pUserName='' and pPassword=''";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIC", txtIC.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pUsername", txtUsername.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPassword", txtPassword.Value);



                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                if (!IsIDExist())
                {
                    Session.Add("ID", id);
                    Session.Add("Username", txtUsername.Value);
                    Session.Add("Password", txtPassword.Value);
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Value, true);
                    Response.Redirect("registered.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    lblErrorMessage.Text = "IC Already Exist";
                }
            }


            /*
            catch (Exception)
            {
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "IC does not exist";
            }
            */

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your last line, do you means this WHERE pIC = @pIC and pUserName="" and pPassword =""";

Comment: yes... you need to add two more conditions to where clause

Comment: @Jordjmax: sorry my mistake, try with single quotes, see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks, but now if I entered S9583728F in the textbox and click sign up, it will redirect me to registered.aspx. I want it to stay at the page and prompt a error in a label saying this NRIC already have a username and password.  @Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: @Jordjmax: ok well first tell me is it Updating the records where UID and Password is empty?

Comment: no. Now is prompt error in label if username and password is not empty  if the NRIC that the person entered already exist in database. etc S9583728F entered, see second image. @Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: 1. If NRIC entered doesn't exist in database, prompt IC does not exist.[SOLVED] 2. If NRIC matches the value in any record in database (assuming username and password in database is empty), update that username and password entered to that record. [SOLVED] 3. If NRIC matches the value in any record in database, (assuming username and password in database not empty), prompt error saying this NRIC already have a username and password. [NOT SOLVED] @Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: Hmm , I don;t know where to place that function @Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46694/discussion-between-jordjmax-and-sudhakar-tillapudi)

Comment: Did you edited it? feels the same. There wrote edited 1 hour ago tho. @Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: @Jordjmax: check it now

Comment: U mean the complete code right. still the same thing, see my error image again, the same thing. @Sudhakar Tillapudi